# Showing a function is harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U(x,y)=$Im$(z^2+3z+5)$ where $z=x+iy$. To show $U$ is harmonic, I could go through the effort of substituting $x+iy$ for each $z$ in $z^2+3z+5$, then I'd have to simplify it enough to find just the imaginary part (which is $3y+2xy$ in this case). Then it is easy to show $U_{xx}+U_{yy}=0$.

The above procedure is a bit tedious though.

The function $z^2+3z+5$ is entire so the Cauchy Riemann* equations hold. I want to leap directly to "therefore Im$(z^2+3z+5)$ is harmonic" but I am unsure if this is possible. I want to argue something along the lines of: "Since $U(x,y)=3y+2xy$ is a first degree polynomial, its first partial derivatives will be constant and its second partial derivatives will be zero, hence $U_{xx}+U_{yy}=0$."

Is this acceptable? Am I missing more to the argument? Or, should I just stick to the tedious argument detailed in the first paragraph?

---

$ $* By Cauchy-Riemann equations I mean $U_x=V_y$ and $U_y=-V_x$.

Comment: Or use that argument that a complex analytic function is harmonic.

Comment: ^ and in case that's unfamiliar to you, just take the $x$ derivative of both sides of the first Cauchy-Riemann equation you listed, and take the $y$ derivative of the second equation. Adding them should give you the result.

Comment: yes, real and imaginary part of holomorphic function is harmonic so your argument is correct.